# Detect the specific element and scroll to vertically down

Tags: javascript

I have an item page and each item has an "image link", hovering mouse over image link a tool tip is shown describing the item. My page is scrollable that indicates good amount of items are viewed. My problem is when I am at the bottom of the page, and put mouse over the "image Link" the tool-tip is not fully shown [half is covered by the window]. So What I want is as soon as I am on the image link and if I see the tool-tip will not be fully shown, I will scroll down the page by the amount of width pixel of the tool-tip. I tried this, but this happens for all image link, but I need for the last image-link in the page visibile area. [I need javascript help]

```
   var totalHeight, currentScroll, visibleHeight
    currentScroll = GetScrollTop();
    totalHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
    visibleHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;


    if (e.pageY <= currentScroll + visibleHeight) {  //This is always true         
        window.scrollTo(0, currentScroll + 100);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an edge-aware tooltip

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/

Comment: Thanks, but i checked lot of edge-sensitive tool-tip they didnt get the scrollbar down to make the tool-tip visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
screenH = window.screen.height; //THIS WILL VISBLE SCREEN HEIGHT
a = window.scrollY; //this will give current y- scroll  positon 
if(a > screenH){
 window.scrollTo(0, a + 100);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @druveen This is for plain check. when I see the "image-link" at the bottom [viewable height], when I put mouse over that, I need it to identify where I am [location of linke-image], and if I see the tool-tip is not fully shown, user will see the scroll bar gets vertically down and the tooltip is fully visible. I have tested lot's tool-tip those are edge-sensitive, but didnt find the way it scroll down to view the tool-tip, my requirement is that. If I could find a attaching opportunity here, I cud depict the problem using image.  Thanks for prompt reply.

Comment: Have u tried with wz_tooltip.js in this tool tip will adjust properly this is not edge sensitive..

Comment: I have given tries from here eactaull [link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/index.html)

Comment: Do you think wz_tooltip.js will meet my requirement?

Comment: get cursor position on mouse of that image 
    $("#img").mousemove(function(e){
       global_mouseY_pos = e.pageY;
    });

Comment: Yes I have the curros position I meant I got the currently clicked Y poistion, then what's the next logic?

Comment: Possibly all parameters I have, but just need to make the logic is, "if (I am at the bottom of the page for that image Link) then increase the scrollbar verttically sae 250 pix.

Comment: @druveen "wz_tooltip.js" will not fit my requriement

Comment: so  if( global_mouseY_pos > screenH){
 window.scrollTo(0, global_mouseY_pos + 100);
} might work. n sorry for wz_tooltip.js

Comment: @druveen, this logic  works only for the first load of the page, and when the screenH=1050[say], when it exceeds the currentY[1050] position,  then the above condition is true for all items, and it scroll downs for all items too..

Comment: Just imagine the total height of the page [totalHeight = document.body.offsetHeight [3640], and I have more that 200 hundred items, I want to scroll down only for the last item.

Comment: Correction: I want to scroll down only for the last item that I see in the entire scrollable window.